# Email Notification for K2 Comment (Joomla)

Tags: php, email, joomla, notifications, k2

Is there anyway to get ***Email Notification*** when user gave comments on my articles?

I'm using **K2** component (**Joomla**). I just found the paid plugins for the email notifier.I don't want to use them and I have tried to put the emails in *'**Comment reports recipient**'* input box from K2 Comment Configuration but it didn't work.